# Портятся данные после извлечения флешки

Tags: железо

Купил флешку из китая, теоретически, Transcend JetFlash 790K на 64 GB.

Но столкнулся со странной проблемой - во второй половине флешки (именно во второй - смотрел расположение файлов в дефрагментаторе - все повреждённые находятся во второй половине) данные теряются после её извлечения. Т. е. если не извлекать, то всё на месте, но как только извлечёшь (безопасно) и вставишь снова, записанные данные (содержимое файлов, сами файлы, вроде на месте) отличаются. При этом на повреждённых данных значительно падает скорость чтения:

[image: скриншот проверки]

Сегодня её разобрал (там всё на защёлках, никакого клея):

[image: фото разобранной флешки]

Я не знаю, но мне кажется, что квадратная штуковина - это контроллер, а две большие прямоугольные (с двух сторон) - непосредственно память.
Ниже фото всех маркировок, чтобы их можно было прочитать.

На одной стороне:

[image: надпись на контроллере]

[image: надпись на первой памяти]

И на обратной:

[image: надпись на второй памяти]

[image: надпись на второй памяти]

Сначала я думал, что надписи на обеих сторонах одинаковые, но потом заметил, что на стороне с контроллером написано `3YND`, а на обратной `3YNL`. Впрочем, понятия не имею, что это означает.

#### Что меня интересует:

1. Что должно быть не так с флешкой, чтобы данные терялись именно после извлечения?
2. Нормально ли вообще для флешки иметь два блока с памятью (если я правильно понимаю, что это они)?
3. Если один из этих блоков повреждён, то почему работает больше половины флешки? Объём раздела 62 911 283 200, но первая ошибка появляется на 0x7c1c9c000 (это 33 315 995 648), что на 1.7 ГБ больше половины.
4. Это больше похоже на случайный брак или продаётся намеренно?
5. Это оригинальная флешка или подделка? Пытался найти фото внутренностей настоящей флешки, но ничего лучше [этого видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5h6oEtmNrA) не нашёл. По коду на корпусе проверку на сайте transcend'а проходит успешно. Светодиод красный, но светит через синий ползунок.
6. Чем-то ещё её можно проверить?

#### И с какой целью оно меня интересует:

1. Насколько я понимаю, конкретно эту флешку без уменьшения объёма починить невозможно. После уменьшения размера раздела должно работать нормально. Какой объём лучше выбрать - 32 ГБ (работающая без ошибок часть) или же половину полного объёма (типа одна из двух планок)?
2. Безопасно ли использовать весь объём флешки для каких-то промежуточных файлов (например, конвертирование видео или файл подкачки), если компьютер не будет выключаться, или же в них со временем тоже будут наблюдаться косяки?
3. Стоит ли относиться даже к работающей части с опасениями (например, не устанавливать на неё систему и не запускать с неё исполняемые файлы)?
4. Способен ли тот же продавец прислать хорошую флешку? Потому что привлекает ценой и высокой скоростью чения и записи.

Comment: Предположу, что до извлечения данные из битых блоков просто лежат где-то в кэше ОС и оттого успевают нормально читаться

Comment: Зачем вы задублировали фото?

Comment: @andreymal, кэш размером в 30 гигов - это как-то маловероятно, не? Причём, на двух разных компьютерах проверялось - результат одинаковый.

Comment: @Kromster, там разные надписи освещены, соответственно их лучше видно. А на первой паре с разных сторон фото - все детали перевёрнуты.

Comment: @andreymal, кстати, порты usb3 сохраняют питание при выключении компа. Есть идея проверить так: записать, выключить комп, потом включить снова и проверить. Имеет смысл?

Comment: @Qwertiy не специалист, не знаю) Но результат, наверно, был бы интересен

Comment: У меня был Trascend, он не читается простой копией `dd` из Линукса. Я решил, что это грубая подделка и выбросил. Купите настоящую флешку и будет вам чики пуки.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, этот читается. Но именно это мне и не нравится - ошибок чтения нет, читаются битые данные. Кстати, на вид сделан довольно качественно, всё ровненько, красиво.

Comment: по поводу того, что файлы как бы есть, но битые. _как бы есть_ - это дерево ФС из таблицы размещения файлов. Оно где то в начале лежит и работает исправно, поэтому их наличие и отображается исправно.

Comment: открывайте спор на али, если только пришло, да требуйте возврата денег.

Comment: Попробуйте не на разных компьютерах, а на разных операционках, может быть очень уникальное железо во флешке и драйвер не вникает. Можно даже не искать другой комп, а в виртуальной машине попробовать.

Comment: @teran, со спором я уже разобрался. Но есть мысль купить ещё такую, потому что выглядит как случайный брак (вот если бы данные сразу не писались, то было бы логично, что это намеренно, но они ж портятся после извлечения, значит достаточное количество памяти там стоит). С одной стороны, это как-то тупо - вроде уже и на грабли наступил, с другой - скорости ведь реально очень высокие в моих тестах - 50 запись и 80 чтение - это ж прям шикарно для такой цены (в прошлый раз 890, а на распродаже будет 777 за 64 ГБ).

Answer (score 3):

Есть древняя китайская традиция - прошивать в контролер флешки больший размер, чем есть на самом деле. Выбросьте ее и больше не скупитесь.

> Стоит ли относиться даже к работающей части с опасениями (например, не
>   устанавливать на неё систему и не запускать с неё исполняемые файлы)?

Судя по поведению флешки, у нее испорчен контроллер, намеренно или не намеренно - установить сложно. Использовать такой накопитель опасно.

Флешка - **это не SSD для бедных**. От регулярной перезаписи и плохого температурного режима она быстро отправится на помойку. Хотите скорости - купите SSD.

Флешка не предназначена для обработки и хранения данных, только для переноса.

Comment: Вообще-то цена за гигабайт у флешки больше, чем у ssd, так что покупать флешку вместо ssd я в принципе не собирался.

Comment: @Qwertiy послушайте человека, дело говорит, другое дело если вы готовы идти на такие риски.

Comment: @spectre_it, я вообще-то хотел загрузочный диск с утилитами сделать - при чём тут ssd? А вот риски я как раз хочу понять, какие есть. Для этого и спрашиваю.

Comment: Дело в том , что даже если вы запишите загрузочный диск, и установите на одну, две машины виндовс. Может быть все нормально, но если делать это регулярно, на определенном железе будете получать ошибку установки, или поставите , не установите драйвера, или ...... ит.д.